# Different ways of grepping for large amounts of data

Tags: bash, grep

So I have a huuuuge file and a big list of items that I want to grep out from that file.
For the sake of this example, let the files be denoted thus-

```
seq 1 10000 > file.txt          #file.txt contains numbers from 1 to 10000
seq 1 5 10000 > list            #list contains every fifth number from 1 to 10000
```

My question is, which is the best way to grep out the lines corresponding to 'list' from 'file.txt'

I tried it in two ways-

```
time while read i ; do grep -w "$i" file.txt ; done < list > output
```

That command took - real    0m1.300s

```
time grep -wf list file.txt > output
```

This one was slower, clocking in at- real   0m1.402s.

Is there a better (faster) way to do this? Is there a best way that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, people. I fixed the useless cat. That's a bad habit I need to wean myself off of. I also fixed the error in the second method of grep -f. Anddd I made both of them grep -w for a more scientific test (fewer variables between the two methods).

Comment: I hope my answer below clearly shows a single grep -Fw for your fake data is orders of magnitude faster than running grep in a loop - as for is there a faster way - see my comparisons with awk and sed solutions - for real data the answer is not straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges

this command greps words from list in file.txt

```
time for i in `cat list`; do grep -w "$i" file.txt ; done > output
```

this command greps patterns from file.txt in list

```
time grep -f file.txt list > output
```

you need to fix one file as the source of strings to match and the other file as the target data in which to match strings - also use the same grep options like -w or -F

It sounds like list is the source of patterns and file.txt is target datafile - here are my timings for the original adjusted commands plus one awk and two sed solutions - the sed solutions differ in whether the patterns are given as separate sed commands or one extended regex

timings

```
one grep
real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
2000 output1

loop grep
real    0m10.120s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.212s
2000 output2

awk
real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
2000 output3

sed
real    0m4.260s
user    0m4.211s
sys     0m0.022s
2000 output4

sed -r
real    0m0.144s
user    0m0.085s
sys     0m0.047s
2000 output5
```

script

```
n=10000
seq 1 $n >file.txt             
seq 1 5 $n >list               

echo "one grep"
time grep -Fw -f list file.txt > output1
wc -l output1

echo "loop grep"
time for i in `cat list`; do grep -Fw "$i" file.txt ; done > output2
wc -l output2

echo "awk"
time awk 'ARGIND==1 {list[$1]; next} $1 in list' list file.txt >output3
wc -l output3

echo "sed"
sed 's/^/\/^/;s/$/$\/p/' list >list.sed
time sed -n -f list.sed file.txt >output4
wc -l output4

echo "sed -r"
tr '\n' '|' <list|sed 's/^/\/^(/;s/|$/)$\/p/' >list.sedr
time sed -nr -f list.sedr file.txt >output5
wc -l output5
```

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted, this is correct and makes OP's measurements incorrect. `-f` specifies a source of patterns rather than an input so in the first case OP searches for 20 000 tokens in a 100 000 tokens file, while in the other he searches for 100 000 tokens in a 20 000 tokens file.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I hesitated to give the "right" commandline since the issue really is one or more typos in the question but hard to know where for sure

Comment: [Here's a better timing](https://ideone.com/msdrj1), feel free to include it in your answer.

Comment: Aaron - typos are contagious this morning - you probably want seq 1 5 100000 > patterns

Comment: Woops, right ! Now it takes too long for ideone with 100 000 tokens, I've changed it to 10 000 and am surprised to see that it favors the first option. Maybe have I got another mistake somewhere?

Comment: Well nope, looks like `grep` is slow with large pattern files, and that splitting the pattern file in smaller chunks or iterating the patterns and spawning a `grep` process for each is the way to go. References : https://fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/blog:080727_grep_with_large_pattern_files and http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?16305

Answer (score 1):

You can try `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file.txt list
```

In my system, `awk` is faster than `grep` with the sample data.

**Test:**

```
$ time grep -f file.txt list > out

real    0m1.231s
user    0m1.056s
sys     0m0.175s

$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file.txt list > out1

real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.067s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Thanks for stats ++,  but why would you want to assign value 1 for each `a[$1]` It's auto assigned to zero nop?

Comment: @sjsam, You are right. I forgot that it will initialize to zero. Thanks.

Comment: awk seems to be *much* faster than grep. My question is, will it work even for text matching? Or is this a special case for numeric matching?

Comment: Wellllll... `a[$1]` doesn't REALLY initialize to zero, it initializes to "zero or null" as array elements are "numeric string" type until used, just like any scalar variable. You can see the functional difference if you do `echo '' | awk 'BEGIN{a[3]} $0 == a[3]{print "match"}'` (will output "match") and `echo '' | awk 'BEGIN{a[3]=0} $0 == a[3]{print "match"}'` (will not output anything as awk will assume you're doing a string comparison, not numeric, since $0 is clearly a null string, not a number).

Answer (score 0):

Faster or not, you've useless use of `cat` up there
Why not?

```
grep -f list file.txt   # Aren't files meant other way
```

Or use a bit more customized awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a{print $1;next}' list file.txt
```

Comment: This use of `cat` is worse than useless; it's incorrect if there is whitespace other than newlines in `file.txt`.

Comment: I think you need `-w` too, on your `grep`. And `-F`.

Comment: @chepner, I fixed that cat. Thanks for pointing it out! Maybe I'll remember from now on.